# Where to find Installation Instructions for Fujitsu Primergy server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, drivers

I just installed a PRIMERGY RX300 S8 with Windows Server 2012 R2

The system shipped with a Fujitsu Server View DVD. But I can't find a manual what is the recommanded order to install drivers.

I believed in 2014 you would get a nice wizard like tool which tells you what is missing but a manual would be fine, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

For Fujitsu Servers the installation process is the following

- Boot from ServerView DVD (bootable PE Environment)
- Select `Deployment` from the menu
- Select the operating system and version you want to install, in my case `Hypervisor` and `Hyper-V Server 2012 R2`
- Use either simple or advanced installation method
- Follow the configuration steps
- The setup prompts you to insert the source medium and continues to install windows in unattended mode. Eventually the proper drivers / agents / software is included and installed, too.

It is worth to mention that, if you don't have a fujitsu labled source dvd of your OS setup will likly fail (in my case that happened) if you use express setup. I had to choose advanced and could change the source medium from "fujitsu" to "windows" and everything worked fine.